# Create a row of 3 circles(segmented) using RectF in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics

I want to create graphics similar to this:https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/pie-charts.png.png

I have created a segmented circle using RectF having four different colours.Below is my code:

```
Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);
// Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);

RectF oval = new RectF(10F, 5F, 45F, 5F);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
canvas.drawArc(oval, 0F, 90F, true, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.drawArc(oval, 90F, 90F, true, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawArc(oval, 180F, 90F, true, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawArc(oval, 270F, 90F, true, paint);
canvas.rotate(43);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
```

I want to create a row of 3 more circles like this, but I'm unable to get them because I am unable to identify the exact coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the way you're defining your `RectF`
the 2nd and 4th value are 5f which means the `RectF` has a width of 0:
`public RectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)`

If you make your rectangle bigger, your code is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates that you should put in the `RectF` constructor are relative to the one you have put when creating the bitmap with `Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)`. For instance, with a 100x100 pixels bitmap, and a `RectF` set that way:

```
new RectF(5f, 10f, 85f, 75f);
```

You will end up with the following result (the `ImageView` background is blue to clearly see its bounds):

[image]

As you can see, the limits of the `RectF` are set in the bitmap coordinates, starting horizontally from the left and vertically from the top.

To create three pie charts, you can just create a larger bitmap (here 300x100) and offset the coordinates of the `RectF` for every new chart:

```
private fun drawPieCharts() {
    var bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.config, true)
    // Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into
    val canvas = Canvas(bitMap)

    drawSinglePie(canvas, 0f)
    drawSinglePie(canvas, 100f)
    drawSinglePie(canvas, 200f)

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap)
}

private fun drawSinglePie(canvas: Canvas, horizontalOffset: Float) {
    val oval = RectF(5f + horizontalOffset, 10f, 85f + horizontalOffset, 75f)
    paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    paint.color = Color.GRAY
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 0f, 90f, true, paint)

    paint.color = Color.GREEN
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 90f, 90f, true, paint)

    paint.color = Color.RED
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 180f, 90f, true, paint)

    paint.color = Color.BLACK
    canvas.drawArc(oval, 270f, 90f, true, paint)
}
```

Which will lead to this result:

[image]

But the bitmap may end up stretched like in the above screenshots, so a better solution would be to create a custom view to avoid such pixelation.